# Solve Tic Tac Toe with Constraint satisfaction problem (CSP)

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, constraint-satisfaction

I am solving tic tac toe board game with CSP. To formulate the game as a CSP, I found variables and Domain. variables are the squares in 3 by 3 game board and Domain should be X and O, in my case 1 and 2. Suppose AI is 2 and I am 1. The constraints should be the rules of the game, such as the fact that each position can only have one value and my question is what are other constraints And How do I do the backtracking?

This is my code so far

```
PLAYER_1 = 2
PLAYER_AI = 1

def print_solution(board):
    """Print Tic Tac Toe board
    """
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            print(board[i][j], end= ' ')
            print()

def IsTerminal(board):
    # Vertical win
    for i in range(0, 3):
        if (board[0][i] != 0 and
            board[0][i] == board[1][i] and
            board[1][i] == board[2][i]):
            return board[0][i]

        # Horizontal win
        for i in range(0, 3):
            if (board[i] == [1,1,1]):
                return 1
            elif (board[i] == [2,2,2]):
                return 2

        # Main diagonal win
        if (board[0][0] != 0 and
            board[0][0] == board[1][1] and
            board[0][0] == board[2][2]):
            return board[0][0]

        # Second diagonal win
        if (board[0][2] != 0 and
            board[0][2] == board[1][1] and
            board[0][2] == board[2][0]):
            return board[0][2]
    
    # Is whole board full?
    for i in range(0, 3):
        for j in range(0, 3):
            # There's an empty field, we continue the game
            if (board[i][j] == 0):
                return None
    return 0
    

def is_valid(self, px, py, board):
    if px < 0 or px > 2 or py < 0 or py > 2:
        return False
    elif board[px][py] != 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def CSP(board):
    pass



def solveGame():
    board = [
        [0,0,0],
        [0,0,0],
        [0,0,0]
        ]
    if Current_player == 2:
        while(True):
            px = int(input('Insert the X coordinate: '))
            py = int(input('Insert the Y coordinate: '))
            if is_valid(px, py):
                board[px][py] = 2
                Current_player = 1
                break
            else:
                print('The move is not valid! Try again.')
```

In CSP function I have to use the backtracking. So every time it will check if the move is safe. I mean if the move does not satisfy one of the constraints AI will trackback. If the game ends in a tie, then it means that the CSP was not solved correctly, as there should be a unique solution that results in a win for one of the players.

Also I found a document from chegg. but I dont understand the constraints. Please help me to solve this question

Comment: Can you explain more widely what are you gonna do with that **CSP** function?

Comment: in CSP function I have to tell AI that if his current move is not satisfying one of the constraints, then he should trackback to find a new spot to make his move.  you might solve this without backtracking but thats the concept of CSP from what I know. CSP makes intelligent backtracking. I guess you already know that. you can check out N queen problem solved with CSP look at the  solve_nq_util  method. that is doing the same work as CSP method: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19HkUTpAhElt_nPNI66aL67-2zj7F29hm?usp=sharing

Comment: you should look at N Queen Problem. there are 3 problems solved in the notebook

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question I hope this answer should work :) Hope SO...

```
def CSP(board, col, row):
    if Is_board_full(board):
        return True


    for i in range(row):
        if is_valid(i , col, board):
           board[i][col] = 1

        if CSP(board, col+1, row) == True:
            return True

        board[i][col] = 1

    return False
```

With a new function

```
def Is_board_full(board):
# Is the whole board full?
for i in range(0, 3):
    for j in range(0, 3):
        # There's an empty field, we continue the game
        if (board[i][j] == 0):
            return False

return True
```